# onListitemClick is never used

Tags: java, android

I am  using onListItemClick with simple_list_item_1

```
public class DrinkCategoryActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ListView listDrinks = getListView();
        ArrayAdapter<Drinks> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Drinks>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                Drinks.drinks);

        listDrinks.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    }
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View itemview, int position, int id){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DrinkActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(DrinkActivity.EXTRA_DRINKNO, id);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

It says that **onListItemClick is never used**

When I open my app it doesn't respond to click.
I don't want to use a new layout activity.

I am using list activity which doesn't always require layout

Comment: I'm not sure how you're getting that to compile, but you've got the wrong signature for `onListItemClick()`. The `id` parameter should be a `long`, not an `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use setOnItemClickListener

```
    setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
          Object listItem = list.getItemAtPosition(position);
       } 
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try below

```
public class DrinkCategoryActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drink_category);

         ListView listDrinks = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.your_list_view_id);
    ArrayAdapter<Drinks> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Drinks>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            Drinks.drinks);

    listDrinks.setAdapter(listAdapter);
     listDrinks.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        //Callback logic here for clicked items
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
listDrinks.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
   } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
public class DrinkCategoryActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ListView listDrinks = getListView();
    ArrayAdapter<Drinks> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Drinks>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            Drinks.drinks);

    listDrinks.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    // Add this block
    listDrinks.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, DrinkActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(DrinkActivity.EXTRA_DRINKNO, id);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Remove

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View itemview, int position, int id){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DrinkActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(DrinkActivity.EXTRA_DRINKNO, id);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: error in line: Intent intent = new Intent(this, DrinkActivity.class);Error:(29, 33) error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(<anonymous OnItemClickListener>,Class<DrinkActivity>)
constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnItemClickListener> cannot be converted to String)
constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnItemClickListener> cannot be converted to Context)